# How to initialize field of class in android?

Tags: java, android, initialization

What is the Difference between this :

```
    public class A 
{ 
List<String> myList;
        public A(List<String> list)
 {
        myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        myList = list; 
} 
} 

        public class main extends Activity 
{
        public void func(List<String> l) 
{    A obj = new A(l); 
}
 }
```

and this:

```
      public class A 
    { 
    List<String> myList;
            public A()
     {
            myList = new ArrayList<String>();
             } 
    } 
            public class main extends Activity
     {
            public void func(List<String> l)
     {   
     A obj = new A();
    obj.myList = l;
     } 

}
```

Both of them implementation of use an object of a class in an activity in android but In first  myList initialize correctly and in seconde it is not initializ.Why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference code wise except the fact that in second case you are not initialising the list that is why it is not getting initialized. Change like this, then it will work

```
      A obj = new A();
      l = new ArrayList<String>(); //This is called initialization.
      obj.myList = l;
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

No difference, in first you initialize it with constructor, in second you initialize it later. But instead of this:

```
myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList = list;
```

I prefer this:

```
myList = new ArrayList<String>(list);
```

Comment: That's not the same thing. Your version makes a shallow copy of the list, the original version doesn't.

Comment: @ci_ i believe arrayList a = arrayList b makes a to reference to b, which when b is deleted a becomes null, and it is not desired. Right?

Comment: I don't know if it's desired or not, the original question doesn't say what it should do. All I'm saying is that neither of the two versions in the questions show that behaviour.

Comment: yeah i just wrote "i prefer", but answer for question is no difference